# Implement interface by inherited Class in Java

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have interface `Car`:

```
public interface Car {
    void run();
}
```

Also i have a base class that implements this interface:

```
public class Base implements Car {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //some implementation here
    }
}
```

Also i have one more class that must implement `Car` interface
So why i can not do something like that?

```
public class Der extends Base implements Car  {
   //no implementation of interface here because Base class already implements it
}
```

Why my base class can not implement interface? What is internal reason of this?

Comment: It's `implements`, not `implement`. And `extends` must be before `implements`. So: `public class Der extends Base implements Car`

Comment: `extends` must come before `implements`, for example, `public class Der extends Base implements Car {`, but has already been pointed out, that would the same as using `public class Der extends Base {`

Comment: Your `Base` class is implementing the interface `Car`

Answer (score 4):

When expending from `Base`, your `Der` will of course have the `run` method because it implements the `Car`. So

```
public class Der extends Base {

}
```

is sufficient

If you need to override `run`, you can easily do that. The code would look like

```
public class Der extends Base {

   @Override
   public void run() {
      //do whatever here
   }
}
```

If you need to use `Der` wherever `Car` will be used, you can of course do that.

Finally if you need `Car` to also implement some other interface the syntax would be

```
public class Der extends Base implements SomeInterface{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `Base class` has implemented `Car Interface` and this base class if extended by `Der Class`  then there is no need to again implement Car interface in Der class.

like if

```
Class Base implements Car{

}
```

and then

```
Class Der extends Base{

}
```

Then all the methods in the interface implicitly access in your Der class.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Der implements Car extends Base {
   //no implementation of interface here because Base class already implements it
}
```

you must use extends keyword before implements keywork

right :

```
public class Der extends Base implements Car {
       //no implementation of interface here because Base class already implements it
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Base class (super class of Der) already implements Car interface, hence, there is no need to implement it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

When extending `Base` your `Der` class will have access to the `run` method and will actually be able to be considered as of type `Car`

ie :

```
Car a = new Der();
```

Will be totally valid.

Answer (score 0):

That is why there is no multiple inheritance in java.

see if you provide implementation for `run` method then what about overriden method of     `Base Class`

so for redundancy its not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

**Implements** keyword should come after **Extends** keyword in your example, like below:

```
    public class Der extends Base implements Car  {
          //no implementation of interface here because
          // Base class already implements it
    }
```

No issues if you do the extends and implements in one class, even extending the class i.e. Base which had already implemented same interface i.e. Car.